# Getting the onclose event for a bootstrap datepicker

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I have a datepicker and I am trying to figure out how when the user clicks outside of the box(when the calendar closes) to alert a test message.

Here is my html and some Laravel

```
<input data-id="{{ $scan->id }}" id="{{ $scan->id }}"   placeholder="mm/dd/yyyy" type="bs-date" class="form-control datepicker-test" value="">
```

Here is my jquery, I am not including the script tags or the document.ready

```
$('.datepicker-test').datepicker({
            onClose: function () {
                alert('wow');
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using [boostrap datepicker](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html) you need to change from:

```
$('.datepicker').datepicker({
    onClose: function () {
        alert('wow');
    }
});
```

to:

```
$('.datepicker').datepicker().on('hide', function(e) {
    console.log('wow');
});
```

> [hide event](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/events.html#hide): Fired when the date picker is hidden.

```js
$('.datepicker').datepicker().on('hide', function(e) {
  console.log('wow');
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.7.1/css/bootstrap-datepicker.css"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.7.1/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>


<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="input-group date">
            <input data-id="id1" id="id1"   placeholder="mm/dd/yyyy" type="bs-date" class="form-control datepicker" value="">
            <div class="input-group-addon">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></span>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```